# MATLAB: ismember vs isequal

Tags: matlab, matlab-table

If `A` and `B` are tables (or datasets) having the same the same columns (and in the same order), then an expression like `ismember(A(:, somecols), B(:, somecols))` will produce a boolean array suitable for indexing `A` with, as in

```
A(ismember(A(:, somecols), B(:, somecols)), :)
```

The line above evaluates to a `table` (or `dataset`, depending on the class of `A`) consisting of those rows of `A` that match some row of `B` at the columns specified in `somecols`.

But now suppose that `B` has exactly one row.  More realistically, suppose that the criterion for selecting rows from `A` is simply to match *this one single row* of `B`, say the first one.

One could do this:

```
A(ismember(A(:, somecols), B(1, somecols)), :)
```

The main quibble I have with this is that it is not "semantically clear", because `ismember` is being used, in effect, to test for equality.

It would be semantically clearer if one could write

```
A(isequal(A(:, somecols), B(1, somecols)), :)
```

but this does line not produce the desired results.  (Specifically, it returns no matches even when `A(:, ...)` contains rows matching `B(1, ...)`.)

My question is, what is the predicate that will correctly produce the logical vector corresponding to the question "does this row of `A` match *this* reference row at `somecols`"?

Comment: As @MrAzzaman's answer below suggests, you'd want `eq` (`==`), not `isequal` if you want to index in to the rows of `A`. These are not equivalent. Unfortunately, `eq` has not been written for the table type (probably for the same reasons that it isn't supported for `cell`, `struct`, etc.). If these seem unwieldy, you might consider making a set of utility functions for yourself that simplify the code you need to write.

Answer (score 3):

For the [`table` data type](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) you can also use [`innerjoin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/innerjoin.html), but `ismember` is fairly clear in this case. Consider the `table`s `At` and `Bt`, where `Bt` has two common rows and one unique row:

```
>> A = randi(7,4,5);
>> commonRows = [1 3];
>> B = [A(commonRows,:); randi(2,1,5)+7];
>> At = array2table(A,'VariableNames',sprintfc('C%d',1:size(A,2)))
At = 
    C1    C2    C3    C4    C5
    __    __    __    __    __
    4     1     5     7     7 
    2     6     5     1     4 
    4     4     6     7     4 
    2     7     7     5     6 
>> Bt = array2table(B,'VariableNames',sprintfc('C%d',1:size(A,2)))
Bt = 
    C1    C2    C3    C4    C5
    __    __    __    __    __
    4     1     5     7     7 
    4     4     6     7     4 
    8     8     9     9     9
```

The second output argument of `innerjoin`, `IA`, gives you the indexes of rows in `A` that are also in `B`. As in your example, consider a subset of the columns, specified by `somecols`:

```
>> somecols = [2 5]
somecols =
     2     5
>> [Ct,IA] = innerjoin(At(:,somecols), Bt(1,somecols))
Ct = 
    C2    C5
    __    __
    1     7 
IA =
     1
>> [Ct,IA] = innerjoin(At(:,somecols), Bt(2,somecols))
Ct = 
    C2    C5
    __    __
    4     4 
IA =
     3
>> [Ct,IA] = innerjoin(At(:,somecols), Bt(3,somecols))
Ct = 
   empty 0-by-2 table
IA =
     []
```

If `IA` is empty (or not) is a suitable test:

```
>> [~,IA] = innerjoin(At, Bt(3,:));
>> isempty(IA)
ans =
     1
>> [~,IA] = innerjoin(At, Bt(2,:));
>> isempty(IA)
ans =
     0
```

Or just test the first output, the common table rows:

```
>> isempty(innerjoin(At, Bt(3,:)))
ans =
     1
>> isempty(innerjoin(At, Bt(1,:)))
ans =
     0
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree that with the `ismember` option it may not be immediately clear what you are intending (though there is nothing wrong with it exactly). Another way you could do which I guess might be more semantically clear (though potentially less efficient) is to use `bsxfun` like so:

```
all(bsxfun(@eq,A(:,somecols),B(1,somecols)),2);
```

If you were to expand this into what is essentially happening under the hood, it would be something like:

```
a = A(:,somecols);
b = repmat(B(1,somecols),size(A,1),1);
abeq = all(a == b,2);
A(abeq,:);
```

Basically you're replicating the one `B` row so that it is the same size as `A(:,somecols)` and then comparing each value in each array. Finally, you're checking which rows have a whole row of `true` (by using `all`), which indicates it matches the single row of B.

EDIT: Sorry, apparently I misunderstood the question - if you're using the `table` datatype (which I didn't actually know existed until a few minutes ago - thanks horchler), then this approach probably won't work.

EDIT2: Notlikethat pointed out the existence of the function `rowfun`, which acts on each row in a table. I can't test this (my version of MATLAB isn't new enough) but I assume that something like this would do what you are wanting:

```
A(rowfun(@(x) isequal(B(1,somecols),x),A(:,somecols)),:);
```

Comment: FYI, `bsxfun` and `eq` aren't defined for the `table` datatype unfortunately so neither of your code snippets will work without conversion to another format (which isn't always possible).

Comment: Is `table` a new MATLAB command? I'm still running R2012a, and it doesn't appear to exist for me.

Comment: I think that it's [new as of R2013b](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#btz8s39). I thought that there was something previous but I can't find it. There is [`dataset`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/dataset.html) in the Statistics toolbox which is [supposed to be similar](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/86779-whats-the-difference-between-a-table-new-in-r2013b-and-a-dataset-stats-toolbox).

Comment: Tables also appear to have brought [`rowfun()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/rowfun.html) to the party, for an ever-so-slightly-semantically-cleaner version of this approach

Comment: @Notlikethat: Nice find! There's also [`varfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varfun.html). All `table` method/properties are listed [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/tables.html).